# Why does my filesystem appear to be full to Ubuntu?

Tags: wubi, filesystem, directory

*I have seen some questions and I know that Ubuntu reserves 5% of filesystem to root.* Believe me this is not the case.

I was moving some files from my home folder to another partition and I had to cancel the copying process due to some reason (the copy didn't stop abruptly, I cancelled it). Now when I try to move the remaining files I get error `Error opening file '/media/sda5/Android/carbon/external/icu4c/i18n/ucol_bld.h': No space left on device`. The destination partition has 85Gb free and my source (Ubuntu home) partition has 12Gb free (total of 48Gb, 5% of 48 is not 12).

Is there any other reason why I might get this error? How do i fix it?

Note: The path from which I was moving had a lot of directories and sub-directories. (It was android source actually. So you can imagine.) I don't know if that information might be useful.

**Edit:**
`df -h | grep -v '^none'` gives

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/loop0       48G   34G   12G  75% /
udev            3.9G  4.0K  3.9G   1% /dev
tmpfs           793M  1.4M  792M   1% /run
/dev/sda7        50G   50G  441M 100% /host
/dev/sda9        50G   34G   17G  68% /media/sda9
/dev/sda6       300G  281G   20G  94% /media/sda6
/dev/sda5       300G  221G   80G  74% /media/sda5
```

`df -h -i | grep -v '^none'` gives

```
Filesystem     Inodes IUsed IFree IUse% Mounted on
/dev/loop0       3.0M  874K  2.2M   29% /
udev             989K   578  989K    1% /dev
tmpfs            992K   655  991K    1% /run
/dev/sda7        505K    66  505K    1% /host
/dev/sda9         17M   38K   17M    1% /media/sda9
/dev/sda6         20M  110K   20M    1% /media/sda6
/dev/sda5         81M  1.1M   80M    2% /media/sda5
```

Please note that the partitions in question are `/dev/loop0` and `/dev/sda5`

**Edit 2:**

I just noticed that I am even unable to create new documents in my partition `/dev/sda5` (all the more reason to panic)

**Edit 3:** I fired `sudo strace mv`. [Here is the output](http://paste.ee/p/xEo3K). I don't really understand it a lot.

Comment: Have you checked the hidden trash folders in your home as well as the other partition?

Comment: I right-clicked and then saw "Properties" that gave me the free space. I guess that's the free space *including* the trash.

Comment: Run `dmesg | less` in a Terminal, and see if you can find any meaningful info there. If there is nothing useful in there, go to your `/var/log` folder and try to find the culprit in the log files. They have meaningful names, so you get the idea which one to check out. (You can browse them with a gui tool, like `sudo geany` or `sudo gedit`, if you prefer that way. `sudo ls /var/log` will list you the log files.)

Comment: Please go into a terminal and add to the question the result of these two commands: `df -h | grep -v '^none'` and `df -h -i | grep -v '^none'`. This will give the account of space (the former) and inodes (basically, the number of files) of all filesystems excluding the virtual ones.

Comment: @Rmano - Please see the edit.

Comment: You have /host full, are you sure there is no need of it (like having some temporary directory in it)? --- Is /dev/loop0 an encrypted disk? I have little clue, it's quite a new configuration for me --- try to do `strace cp ...` to see exactly where it fails. Or maybe you have a big file open and deleted that is keep alive by some process and clogs you disk. Difficult to say.

Comment: `/dev/loop0` is not an encrypted disk. My Ubuntu is Wubi installed, though. I even restarted my laptop so I am not sure if the big file which, if at all might have been open, is still open now.

Comment: I fired `sudo strace mv ..` but honestly I can't make a lot out of output. Mind if I paste the output to pastebin?

Comment: Here is the output http://paste.ee/p/hic1K 

I don't really understand it a lot.

Comment: What directory were you in when you ran that cp command?  Was it /media/sda5?  If so, try creating a subdirectory and copying the files there instead.

Comment: The android shared partition should have FAT32 filesystem. You should check it for errors in Windows using `chkdsk`.

Comment: @psusi - I was in home directory when I tried that command. Also I am not able to create any file/directory in /media/sda5

Comment: @Danatela - Its NTFS. But thanks for the suggestion though. I'll do it. Will have to reboot my system.

Comment: @Danatela - Woohoo! Thanks! That helped. I ran `chkdsk E:/f` in Windows in an administrative `cmd` shell(it was my E: drive) and indeed, it found some errors and fixed it. If you could write that as an answer, I'd gladly accept it. Also, I'm adding thw `Wubi` tag to my question because I think this is a Windows/Wubi specific problem

Comment: Lots of files can fill up your inodes, check out the link - http://askubuntu.com/questions/231585/running-out-of-inodes

Comment: @kingmilo - True. But the `df - i` commands outputs that only 29% of my inodes are in use (see 1st edit)

Comment: @TheRookierLearner kool, was just an fyi, it catches a lot of people out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you cancel the copying of file there might appear a problem in the filesystem. So reboot into Windows and run

```
chkdsk /F <drive>
```

It should find and fix errors that can't be fixed inside Ubuntu.

<sup>Offtopic: I dream about such application that would scan disk in Ubuntu without need to boot Windows…</sup>