# "No space left on device" when installing packages, yet I have space left

Tags: dpkg, disk-usage

Whether through update manager, or through terminal, I error out.

When I try `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`:

```
Fetched 1,024 kB in 20s (51.0 kB/s) 
Reading package lists... Done 
Reading package lists... Done 
Building dependency tree Reading state information... Done 
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these. 
The following packages have unmet dependencies: linux-headers-generic : 
Depends: linux-headers-3.13.0-29-generic but it is not installed 
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
```

And When I try `sudo apt-get -f install`:

```
Unpacking linux-headers-3.13.0-29-generic (3.13.0-29.53) ... 
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-headers-3.13.0-29-generic_3.13.0-29.53_amd64.deb 
(--unpack): unable to create /usr/src/linux-headers-3.13.0-29-generic/include/config/inotify/user.h.dpkg-new' (while processing./usr/src/linux-headers-3.13.0-29-generic/include/config/inotify/user.h'): No space left on device 
No apport report written because the error message indicates a disk full error dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe) 
Errors were encountered while processing: /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-headers-3.13.0-29-generic_3.13.0-29.53_amd64.deb 
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

When I open Ubuntu software center, I get the following text:

> New software can't be installed because there is a problem with the
>   software currently installed. Do you want to repair this problem now?

I get the option to 'repair' or 'cancel'. If I hit 'repair', I get the following error:

```
Package operation failed
the installation or removal of a software package failed.
(Reading database ... 417598 files and directories currently installed.) 
Preparing to unpack .../linux-headers-3.13.0-29-generic_3.13.0-29.53_amd64.deb ...   Unpacking linux-headers-3.13.0-29-generic (3.13.0-29.53) ... 
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-headers-3.13.0-29-generic_3.13.0-29.53_amd64.deb 
(--unpack): unable to create /usr/src/linux-headers-3.13.0-29-generic/include/config/bug.h.dpkg-new' (while processing./usr/src/linux-headers-3.13.0-29-generic/include/config/bug.h'): No space left on device 
No apport report written because the error message indicates a disk full error dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe) 
Errors were encountered while processing: /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-headers-3.13.0-29-generic_3.13.0-29.53_amd64.deb 
Error in function: dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-headers-generic: linux-headers-generic depends on linux-headers-3.13.0-29-generic; however: Package linux-headers-3.13.0-29-generic is not installed.
dpkg: error processing package linux-headers-generic (--configure): dependency problems - leaving unconfigured 
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-generic: linux-generic depends on linux-headers-generic (= 3.13.0.29.35); however: Package linux-headers-generic is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing package linux-generic (--configure): dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
```

The disk full error is odd, because none of my disks are full. I know this because when I run `df`, I get the following:

```
Filesystem 1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on 
/dev/sda6   36178648  13162504  21155332  39% /
none               4         0         4   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
udev         3873544        12   3873532   1% /dev
tmpfs         776860      1384    775476   1% /run
none            5120         0      5120   0% /run/lock
none         3884300     25276   3859024   1% /run/shm
none          102400        68    102332   1% /run/user
/dev/sda2  124327968  42583252  81744716  35% /media/sudoer/48AEC994AEC97B48 
/dev/sda3  807468724 121812996 685655728  16% /media/sudoer/New Volume
```

What do I do at this point? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did the above post solve your problem? You haven't replied to the comments or the answer below.

Comment: Possibly related: http://askubuntu.com/questions/89710/how-do-i-free-up-more-space-in-boot

Comment: @Seth nope, is not the /boot directory

Answer (score 22):

On unix file system, file and directory have two part: [**inode**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inode) and data.

In inodes are stored information about file such as permission, owner, change time, access time, and so on.

The total number of inodes **is limited**, so you can get `No space left on device` if you reach such limit even if the disk is not very full.

Use:

```
df -i
```

to view inodes, if you get 100% for `IUse` and 0 `IFree`, this means that you have a lot of **small** file.

For example if you have 2 billions files whose size is 1 byte, you could reach inode limit, but your disk could be not completely full.

If this is your case, try to remove more file you can and than redo `apt-get update`.

Comment: Or move files to a new partition. I would check the `/home` directory first.

Answer (score 1):

You can clean up space in /boot (remove old linux headers etc), with:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

Answer (score 1):

I also encountered this problem. According to the prompt,

> unable to create
>   /usr/src/linux-headers-3.13.0-29-generic/include/...

As explained by Lety, "The total number of inodes is limited". So I deleted some old linux-headers packages using the package manager so `/usr` will have enough inodes, for example `sudo apt-get remove linux-headers-3.13.0-3*`, then I can run `sudo apt-get install -f` to continue the installation.

Comment: You are right. I thought there are temporary files. I will modify my answer. Thank you! @user535733

Answer (score 1):

As @Lety said, the problem is how to find folders with a lot of tiny files which wasted all your inodes (as `df -i` show).

Find heavy packages (like old kernels) with

```
wajig sizes | tail -n 30
```

which requiere `wajig` installed, otherwise:

```
dpkg-query --show --showformat='${Package;-50}\t${Installed-Size}\n' | sort -k 2 -n | grep -v deinstall | awk '{printf "%.3f MB \t %s\n", $2/(1024), $1}'|tail -n 10
```

Use `uname -r` to find current kernel, you don't want to remove it.

Then try:

1. Reboot or try if there is any process to kill which opened a large file which has since been deleted `sudo lsof +L1`
2. Remove unused packages `sudo apt-get autoremove`
3. Clean cache `sudo apt-get clean` or manually on `/var/cache/apt/archives`
4. Use `apt-get remove` or `sudo dpkg --purge` to remove some old kernels or heavy packages.
   Maybe you still get `unable to create /usr/src/linux-headers`...
5. If you get here you will use those slow techniques to find the guilty folder, but first go to the usual suspects using something like `for i in /usr/src/*; do echo $i; find $i |wc -l; done`:

   1. Linux header folders: `/usr/src/linux-headers-*`
   2. Logs: `/var/log/`

Specific folder counters:

- `du --inodes -d 1 /usr/src/ | sort -n`
- `sudo find . -xdev -type f | cut -d "/" -f 2 | sort | uniq -c | sort -n`
- `sudo find . -maxdepth 1 -type d | grep -v '^\.$' | xargs -n 1 -i{} find {} -xdev -type f | cut -d "/" -f 2 | uniq -c | sort -n`

Answer (score 1):

Your [`tmpfs`](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/tmpfs) may be full. `/tmp` lives in your RAM or swap. You can check how much space is being used by running:

```
$ df -h | grep tmpfs
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
tmpfs           3.9G   33M  3.9G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs           3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs           3.9G  3.9G     0 100% /tmp
```

To temporarily increase its size, try the following command:

```
sudo mount -o remount,size=16G,noatime /tmp
```

You can also permanently increase the size through `/etc/fstab`.

Answer (score 1):

I had the problem that there was no space and no inodes on my `/boot` partition left. I tried to remove old kernels via dpkg but it was not doing the trick. After inspecting the folder with `du -h` and `ls -h` I found that most space was used by `initramfs` files.

To uninstall them I had to follow this guide: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RemoveOldKernels

- First I checked which kernel version I was using via `uname -r`
- Then I found other installed kernel versions via `dpkg -l | grep linux-image | grep ii` (the `grep ii` ensures that only installed versions are listed)
- I choose the oldest kernels and used the command `sudo update-initramfs -d -k 4.2.0-15-generic`. I don't know if that is strictly neccessary.
- Then I purged the kernel with `dpkg --purge 4.2.0-15-generic`
- Now I was finally able to run `apt -f install`
- and `sudo apt autoremove`

Answer (score 0):

Running out of inodes on Ubuntu: if below commands showing the same error go to `/usr/src` and delete old kernel(unused) directories so it will resolve the issues.

```
sudo apt-get -f install
sudo apt autoremove
```

For more information, see: https://medium.com/@brucepomeroy/running-out-of-inodes-on-ubuntu-718aef71ac16

Comment: Thank you, this answer contains useful tips and information however they are expressed in an unclear manner. I hope that someone can edit it and improve it so that it becomes clear and easy to understand.