# Can't install or uninstall software. Unmet dependencies. apt-get -f install does not work

Tags: apt, package-management, kernel, updates, dpkg

I seem to have plenty of space on boot.  I have whole disk encryption.

First:

```
$ sudo apt-get install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 linux-image-extra-3.13.0-67-generic : Depends: linux-image-3.13.0-67-generic but it is not installed
 linux-image-generic : Depends: linux-image-3.13.0-67-generic but it is not installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
```

Then:

```
$ sudo apt-get -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  bbswitch-dkms dkms fonts-dejavu fonts-dejavu-extra lib32gcc1 libc6-i386
  libcuda1-331 libvdpau1 linux-headers-3.13.0-32
  linux-headers-3.13.0-32-generic linux-headers-3.13.0-37
  linux-headers-3.13.0-37-generic linux-headers-3.13.0-40
  linux-headers-3.13.0-40-generic linux-image-3.13.0-32-generic
  linux-image-3.13.0-37-generic linux-image-3.13.0-40-generic
  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-32-generic linux-image-extra-3.13.0-37-generic
  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-40-generic linux-image-generic nvidia-prime
  nvidia-settings screen-resolution-extra ttf-dejavu ttf-dejavu-core
  ttf-dejavu-extra
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following extra packages will be installed:
  linux-image-3.13.0-67-generic
Suggested packages:
  fdutils linux-doc-3.13.0 linux-source-3.13.0 linux-tools
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  linux-image-3.13.0-67-generic
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/15.2 MB of archives.
After this operation, 42.5 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
(Reading database ... 650322 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../linux-image-3.13.0-67-generic_3.13.0-67.110_amd64.deb ...
Done.
Unpacking linux-image-3.13.0-67-generic (3.13.0-67.110) ...
No apport report written because the error message indicates a disk full error
                                                                              dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-3.13.0-67-generic_3.13.0-67.110_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 unable to create `/boot/config-3.13.0-67-generic.dpkg-new' (while processing `./boot/config-3.13.0-67-generic'): No space left on device
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Examining /etc/kernel/postrm.d .
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools 3.13.0-67-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-67-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub 3.13.0-67-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-67-generic
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-3.13.0-67-generic_3.13.0-67.110_amd64.deb
[ Rootkit Hunter version 1.4.0 ]
File updated: searched for 168 files, found 137
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
nate@saturn:~$
```

Picture of System Monitor showing disk Space:

[image: System Monitor Showing Disk Space]

Answer (score 0):

On unix file system, file and directory have two part: inode and data.

In inodes are stored information about file such as permission, owner, change time, access time, and so on.

The total number of inodes is limited, so you can get No space left on device if you reach such limit even if the disk is not very full.

Use:

df -i

to view inodes, if you get 100% for IUse and 0 IFree, this means that you have a lot of small file.

For example if you have 2 billions files whose size is 1 byte, you could reach inode limit, but your disk could be not completely full.

If this is your case, try to remove more file you can and than redo apt-get update.

Source: https://askubuntu.com/a/486806/232329