# sound is not working in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04

To overcome my sound issues while installing pulseaudio i'm getting error as.....

```
Selecting previously unselected package pulseaudio.
(Reading database ... 236761 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../pulseaudio_1%3a4.0-0ubuntu11_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking pulseaudio (1:4.0-0ubuntu11) ...
Selecting previously unselected package pulseaudio-module-x11.
Preparing to unpack .../pulseaudio-module-x11_1%3a4.0-0ubuntu11_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking pulseaudio-module-x11 (1:4.0-0ubuntu11) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.6.7.1-1) ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-16) ...
Setting up initramfs-tools (0.103ubuntu4.2) ...
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
lzma: (stdout): Write error: No space left on device
dpkg: error processing package initramfs-tools (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Setting up pulseaudio (1:4.0-0ubuntu11) ...
Setting up pulseaudio-module-x11 (1:4.0-0ubuntu11) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.19-0ubuntu6) ...
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: I think its a duplicate issue . Please refer https://askubuntu.com/questions/317763/apt-get-no-space-left-on-device-12-04
and https://askubuntu.com/questions/485743/no-space-left-on-device-when-installing-packages-yet-i-have-space-left

Answer (score 0):

Try install pulseaudio after the installation fails follow below steps

```
sudo apt-get -f install 
sudo apt-get install pulseaudio
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend that you try running

```
sudo alsa force-reload
```

as that usually fixes the problem for me.