# Why no Space on my HardDrive? Storage Summary on login different from df -h output

Tags: partitioning, disk-usage

My Email service (Zimbra) has stopped and its crying low disk space via the warning: `WARNING: Disk space below threshold for /opt/zimbra/store.`.

On investigation, I've found the weirdest thing I've seen in Ubuntu in forever. When I login via SSH, I get the usual summary of the server including the storage. It states:

```
=> / is using 90.9% of 12.79GB
=> /mail is using 94.9% of 88.58GB
```

When I do a `df -h` the output shows that on /mail I only have 4kilobytes left and that usage is 100%?

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1        13G   12G  532M  96% /
udev            1.7G  4.0K  1.7G   1% /dev
tmpfs           343M  256K  343M   1% /run
none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none            1.7G     0  1.7G   0% /run/shm
dev/sdb5        89G   85G  4.0K 100% /mail  <============This is what is crazy
```

I have Nagios on a remote server and it reads that I have 94.9% usage just like in the login summary. So is `df - h` giving the wrong results which then makes zimbra die?

@Jakke:

`df -ih` output as below:

```
Filesystem     Inodes IUsed IFree IUse% Mounted on
/dev/sda1        832K  235K  598K   29% /
udev             427K   443  426K    1% /dev
tmpfs            429K   323  429K    1% /run
none             429K     6  429K    1% /run/lock
none             429K     1  429K    1% /run/shm
/dev/sdb5        5.7M  378K  5.3M    7% /mail
```

**Additional Info:**

A while ago the /mail partition was full and I added 10GB space into the /mail partition using gparted and space moved from 80GB to 90GB. Could that be affecting it?

Using Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS

Comment: what is the output of `df -ih`? This will display inodes as well. Maybe you ran out...

Comment: @Jakke I've added the output of `df -ih`. what does that output mean?

Comment: The partition has probably run out of available inodes. Take a look at [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/231585/running-out-of-inodes) question.

Answer (score 1):

I would rather use ncdu it has saved me several times from such errors. I noticed over time, that some directories when they contain a lot of files, they report crazy size. This happened to me several times and on different hard drives on different servers.
To get ncdu which stands for no curse disk usage

```
sudo apt-get install ncdu
```