# t2.micro Ubuntu 16.04 ran out of space - Debug help

Tags: disk-usage, ruby, amazon-ec2, aws

My AWS t2.micro (Ubuntu 16.04) comes with 1G disk space.

But, at 124 MB, I'm seeing out of space error.

*/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/libexec/rbenv-init: line 131: cannot create temp file for here-document: No space left on device*

```
ubuntu@ip:~/temp/saas-mush/saas-mash$ du -sh ~/*
4.0K /home/ubuntu/certbot.log
4.0K /home/ubuntu/Downloads
4.0K /home/ubuntu/puma.conf
4.0K /home/ubuntu/puma-manager.conf
124M /home/ubuntu/temp
```

Why does this happen?

I'm not able to build my modules because my ruby bundle installer is failing with this error.

*No space left on device @ rb_sysopen - /tmp/captured_stderr20170902-4255-pdr8yg (Errno::ENOSPC)*

Also ran this, if that helps

```
ubuntu@ip:~$ df -h /home/
Filesystem Size Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/xvda1 7.8G 5.4G 2.1G 73% /


ubuntu@ip:~$ df -i
Filesystem     Inodes  IUsed  IFree IUse% Mounted on
udev           124466    352 124114    1% /dev
tmpfs          126787    367 126420    1% /run
/dev/xvda1     524288 524288      0  100% /
none           126787      3 126784    1% /sys/fs/cgroup
none           126787      3 126784    1% /run/lock
none           126787      2 126785    1% /run/shm
none           126787      2 126785    1% /run/user
cgmfs          126787     14 126773    1% /run/cgmanager/fs
tmpfs          126793      1 126792    1% /run/user/1000
```

Have also posted this on AWS EC2 Forums
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=802970&#802970

Appreciate any help on this!

Comment: What about `df -i`?

Comment: Filesystem     Inodes  IUsed  IFree IUse% Mounted on
udev           124466    352 124114    1% /dev
tmpfs          126787    367 126420    1% /run
/dev/xvda1     524288 524288      0  100% /
none           126787      3 126784    1% /sys/fs/cgroup
none           126787      3 126784    1% /run/lock
none           126787      2 126785    1% /run/shm
none           126787      2 126785    1% /run/user
cgmfs          126787     14 126773    1% /run/cgmanager/fs
tmpfs          126793      1 126792    1% /run/user/1000

Comment: Formatting is bad here. @Michael-sqlbot. Edited it into the post. Looking like the instance ran out of inodes!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because of the instance running out of inodes. Check this post on [running out of inodes](https://askubuntu.com/questions/231585/running-out-of-inodes) for debugging the regular way.

I solved this by adding additional storage to my volume and doing [appropriate configuration](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24027/how-can-i-resize-an-ext-root-partition-at-runtime). Please note that additional storage may cost you.