# Problems upgrading system

Tags: 16.04, upgrade, updates, disk, amazon-ec2

My system is running on a AWS EC2 instance. Basic micro instance. I run the command:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

everything appears to be okay...and now

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

this is where I get this return message

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
   linux-headers-4.4.0-87-generic : Depends: linux-headers-4.4.0-87 but it is 
not installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
```

and then this...

```
root@ip-172-31-18-25:/# apt-get install -f
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer 
required:
  libecap3 libltdl7 linux-headers-4.4.0-51 linux-headers-4.4.0-51-generic
  linux-headers-4.4.0-53 linux-headers-4.4.0-53-generic linux-headers-4.4.0-57
  linux-headers-4.4.0-57-generic linux-headers-4.4.0-59
  linux-headers-4.4.0-59-generic linux-headers-4.4.0-62
  linux-headers-4.4.0-62-generic linux-headers-4.4.0-63
  linux-headers-4.4.0-63-generic linux-headers-4.4.0-64
  linux-headers-4.4.0-64-generic linux-headers-4.4.0-66
  linux-headers-4.4.0-66-generic linux-headers-4.4.0-70
  linux-headers-4.4.0-70-generic linux-headers-4.4.0-71
  linux-headers-4.4.0-71-generic linux-headers-4.4.0-72
  linux-headers-4.4.0-72-generic linux-headers-4.4.0-75
  linux-headers-4.4.0-75-generic linux-headers-4.4.0-78
  linux-headers-4.4.0-78-generic linux-headers-4.4.0-79
  linux-headers-4.4.0-79-generic linux-image-4.4.0-51-generic
  linux-image-4.4.0-53-generic linux-image-4.4.0-57-generic
  linux-image-4.4.0-59-generic linux-image-4.4.0-62-generic
  linux-image-4.4.0-63-generic linux-image-4.4.0-64-generic
  linux-image-4.4.0-66-generic linux-image-4.4.0-70-generic
  linux-image-4.4.0-71-generic linux-image-4.4.0-72-generic
  linux-image-4.4.0-75-generic linux-image-4.4.0-78-generic
  linux-image-4.4.0-79-generic snap-confine
  Use 'apt autoremove' to remove them.
  The following additional packages will be installed:
   linux-headers-4.4.0-87
  The following NEW packages will be installed:
  linux-headers-4.4.0-87
 0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 56 not upgraded.
 8 not fully installed or removed.
 Need to get 0 B/9,892 kB of archives.
 After this operation, 70.6 MB of additional disk space will be used.
 Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
 (Reading database ... 513496 files and directories currently installed.)
 Preparing to unpack .../linux-headers-4.4.0-87_4.4.0-87.110_all.deb ...
  Unpacking linux-headers-4.4.0-87 (4.4.0-87.110) ...
  dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-headers-
  4.4.0-87_4.                                                                                                                                                             
 4.0-87.110_all.deb (--unpack):
  unable to create '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.4.0-
  87/arch/x86/include/asm/alternat                                                                                                                                                             
  ive-asm.h.dpkg-new' (while processing './usr/src/linux-headers-4.4.0-
  87/arch/x86                                                                                                                                                             
  /include/asm/alternative-asm.h'): No space left on device
  No apport report written because the error message indicates a disk full error
                                                                          dp                                                                                                                                                             
  kg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
  Errors were encountered while processing:
  /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-headers-4.4.0-87_4.4.0-87.110_all.deb
 E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Yes, I realize it says disk is full, however it is in fact not even close to being full...

```
  root@ip-172-31-18-25:/# df -Th
  Filesystem     Type      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
  udev           devtmpfs  487M     0  487M   0% /dev
  tmpfs          tmpfs     100M  3.0M   97M   4% /run
  /dev/xvda1     ext4      7.8G  4.4G  3.1G  59% /
  tmpfs          tmpfs     496M     0  496M   0% /dev/shm
  tmpfs          tmpfs     5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
  tmpfs          tmpfs     496M     0  496M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
  tmpfs          tmpfs     100M     0  100M   0% /run/user/1000
```

**Edit**:

**I checked the `df -i` and it said boot was full.** I was sick of this problem so I just ended up terminating the instance. I have terminated many instances on aws ec2, seems like I was forever running into problems. Seems like you need to have a IT/Server specialist to host a simple website, disgusting. Why Ubuntu developers?? Was it because I was running

```
   sudo apt-get
```

instead of

```
   sudo apt
```

what a nuisance. it shouldn't be this hard.

Comment: Please run `sudo apt autoremove`

Comment: Is /boot full ?

Comment: I have tried sudo apt autoremove. Also tried sudo apt clean. I see check to see if /boot is full.

Comment: Out of inodes... `df -i`.

Comment: The instance has been  terminated.

Comment: @starkus Can you post an answer if you think that will work? [Leaving a half-answer as a comment](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/2281/please-stop-posting-half-answers-and-dumb-advice-as-comments) can often cause more harm than good. In this case I don't know why removing those old `.deb` files would help, nor why you recommend doing it that way instead of just running `sudo apt clean`. I see how `sudo apt-get update` may be helpful but it seems totally separate (the `update` action is unaffected by those files). But if you post an answer I think you'll be able to explain it more clearly.

Comment: This is most likely the answer to this problems... https://askubuntu.com/questions/231585/running-out-of-inodes